# Get last and minimal values from grouped documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

My document model looks like:

```
{
    "model": "ABC123",
    "date": "2018-12-24T23:00:00.000+0000",
    "price": "2000" ,
}
```

I would like to retrive collection to get array of documents:

```
[
  { "_id" : "ABC123", "newestDate" : ISODate("2018-12-26T23:00:00Z"), "newestPrice" : 2801.33, "lowestPriceAtAll": 1300 }, 
{ "_id" : "ABC124", "newestDate" : ISODate("2018-12-26T23:00:00Z"), "newestPrice" : 2801.33, "lowestPriceAtAll": 990}
]
```

where `_id` is `model` field, `newestPrice` is price of newest document (grouped by `model`) and `lowestPriceAtAll` is lowest price in all documents with the same `model`.

I grilled two queries.
First is to find lowest price documents:

```
   offers.aggregate([ 
        { $sort: { "model": 1, "price": 1 }}, 
        { 
            $group: { 
                _id: "$model", 
                lowestPrice: { "$first": "$price" },
                lowestPriceDate: { "$first": "$date"},
            }
        }
    ])
```

the second is to find newest documents:

```
offers.aggregate([ 
        { $sort: { "model": 1, "date": -1 }}, 
        { 
            $group: { 
                _id: "$model", 
                newestDate: { "$first": "$date" },
                newestPrice: { "$first": "$price"},
            }
        }
    ])
```

Is it possible to merge these two queries into one? (the most important thing is that documents have to be grouped by `model` field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$facet`

```
db.offers.aggregate([ 
    {$facet :{
        lowest: [
            { $sort: { "model": 1, "price": 1 }}, 
            { 
                $group: { 
                    _id: "$model", 
                    lowestPrice: { "$first": "$price" },
                    lowestPriceDate: { "$first": "$date"},
                }
            }
            ],
        newest: [
            { $sort: { "model": 1, "date": -1 }}, 
            { 
                $group: { 
                    _id: "$model", 
                    newestDate: { "$first": "$date" },
                    newestPrice: { "$first": "$price"},
                }
            }
        ]
    }}
])
```